# Reset index on condition sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I have the following db in sql

| id | time | lag | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 2021-01-01 | null | 1 |
| x | 2021-01-02 | 1 | 2 |
| x | 2021-01-05 | 3 | 3 |
| x | 2021-01-15 | 10 | 4 |
| x | 2021-02-28 | 43 | 5 |
| x | 2021-03-01 | 2 | 6 |
| x | 2021-03-05 | 4 | 7 |

lag is the differences in date between the date and the previous date

what i want is the row_num to reset if the lag is exceeded 30days

| id | time | lag | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 2021-01-01 | null | 1 |
| x | 2021-01-02 | 1 | 2 |
| x | 2021-01-05 | 3 | 3 |
| x | 2021-01-15 | 10 | 4 |
| x | 2021-02-28 | 43 | 1 |
| x | 2021-03-01 | 2 | 2 |
| x | 2021-03-05 | 4 | 3 |

tks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "reset" ?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean to reset? start from 1? for all records or just for that which has 30+ lag?

Comment: May be its update

Comment: AFAI understand, `row_num` looks like the number of records before lag < 30, so if lag>30 then it should start counting from 1 again _from the row lag>30_ . Is this the case or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, for reset I mean start from 1 again

Comment: @mcy Yes u're correct, can u provide any solution? tkx

Comment: also, which database.  SQL is generic... MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(grp),
  row_number() over(partition by id, grp order by time) row_num
from (
  select * except(gap),
    countif(gap > 30) over(partition by id order by time) grp
  from (  
    select *, 
      date_diff(time, lag(time) over(partition by id order by time), day) gap
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Tks, I tried the code and it's worked